# What does "withdraw into" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, phrasal-verbs

What does "withdraw into" mean  in the following sentence?

> Many depressed people just **withdraw into** themselves.

Comment: Have you tried typing the phrase *withdraw into* into the Google search box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **withdraw** comes from Middle English and still means to draw or take back, like if you withdraw your hand when you're done holding hands with someone.

A newer definition of withdraw is to **stay away from others** or **stop participating in something**.

**withdraw into oneself** means
**to become introverted** or **to concern oneself with one's inner thoughts**.

> I have to struggle to keep from withdrawing into myself.

Answer (score 2):

"Withdraw into oneself" is an idiom and according to [**TheFreeDictionary**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/withdraw+into+oneself) it means:

> to become introverted; to concern oneself with one's inner thoughts.

For example:

> After a few years of being ignored, she **withdrew into herself**.